# How to find the common elements of two lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the common elements of two lists using python 3, and have a new list with the common elements appearing only once. This is what I have so far:

```
lengtha = len(lista);
lengthb = len(listb);

identical = [];
checker = 0;

for i in range (0, lengtha-1):
    for j in range (0, lengthb-1):
        if lista[i] == listb[j]:
            length = len(identical);
            for h in range (0, length-1):
                if lista[i] == identical[h]:
                checker = 1;
            if checker == 0:
                identical.append(list[i]);
            checker = 0;
```

When I tried it with the lists

```
lista = ['hello', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog']
listb = ['hello', 'cat', 'cat', 'mouse', 'whale', 'whale', 'elephant', 'whale', 'elephant', 'dog', 'dog']
```

The result was `['hello','cat','cat','dog']`. I can't figure out why `'cat'` shows up twice and other duplicated animals didn't.

Comment: Consolidate to `list(set(lista).intersection(set(listb)))`

Comment: `list(set(a) & set(b))` ?

Comment: as an aside, your indentation is off

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sets`, its like a list, but can only hold unique items:

```
set(lista).intersection(listb)
```

Comment: Note that this requires your list elements to be hashable.